# Verify Date and Time For Report Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with an input page that logs data on subsequent sheets. A macro will allow the user to input three date and time pieces for verifying how the data should be stored.

For example there is a Morning, Mid-Day, and Evening Report button; upon clicking the macro will verify the date and time fit into the appropriate window. My times are 8:00, 16:00, and 0:00 with the following code verifying the time falls into the correct window:

```
If Continue And reportdate - Int(reportdate) <> 0.33 Then
    MsgBox ("The date and time are not correct for the Morning Report. Please change the time/date or select one of the other reports.")
    Continue = False
End If
```

reportdate is the user input date and time for the report. The arithmetic  = 0.33 and in my mind I am saying if the date and time doesn't match this value then the time frame isn't correct and a different report should be run. However, when I run this code for 8am the macro says it doesn't fall in the correct time window.

Comment: So you expect 08:00 to be equal to 0.33 ? How?

Comment: Because if reportdate = 06/24/2022 08:00, you can take a spreadsheet and input the following formula 06/24/2022 08:00 - Int(06/24/2022 08:00) = 0.33. Another reason is because it's 1/3 or 0.33 of the 24 hour period.

Comment: Then somewhere you are not calculating or testing what you think you are…

Comment: I just can't figure out what because when I use 0.25 or 1/4 and input say 6:00am for the time it works as expected.

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to use the set of VBA Date functions.

Comment: Would you be able to share an alternate you would recommend performing this task please?

Comment: Test for 08:00, 16:00 and 00:00

Comment: None of them work. Do you suppose it has something to do with floating points? The variables are Singles. But what is really confusing me is if I change it to 0.25 and input 6:00am it works fine.

Comment: Would help to include the declaration for `reportdate` and how you populate its value.  In any case 8:00am isn't 0.33, it's 0.333333333333333, up to Excel's limit of precision.  `reportdate - Int(reportdate) <> 1/3` gives me `False` for a cell with value `8:00:00 AM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so as mentioned 0.33 is not actually 8am, it appears to be 7:55:12.

Using a stop and the locals window:

```
    differenceValue = eightAm - midNight
    Stop
```

Gives a difference value of 0.333333333335759.
You could use that or set up a differneceValue as above and compare to that.
Let me know if it works